# Проблема кодировки на Java сервере (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql

Есть сервер на Java. БД mysql. Так создал базу данных:

```
CREATE DATABASE `my_db` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

После, если ввожу в командную строку команды `insert into`, все окей, но вот если я пытаюсь ввести в программе русские символы, то вместо букв выходят вопросы.

Вот код простого запроса на сервер.  Может тут что нибудь нужно написать?

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          System.out.println("connect");
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
          Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
          statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `msg` (`text`)VALUES('текс какой нить');");

      } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(DBJava.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          System.out.println("cath:".concat(ex.getMessage()));
      }
    System.out.print("end");
  }
}
```

Пробовал перекодировать строку

```
String str = new String("текс какой нить".getBytes("utf8"));
```

Comment: Попробуйте сразу после подключения к БД выполнить запрос `SET NAMES utf8` и после него уже делайте вставку в таблицу.

Comment: при подключении к БД указывайте кодировку, рекомендуют что то вроде `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "user", "pass");`

Comment: не помогает ни оди из вариатов

Comment: если напрямую в БД вставлять русский текст проблема остается?

Comment: @Виктор  нет если я вручную пишу в командной строке то нормально отображается и все хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановил сервер на последний и вроде все в норме